# Signal parameter in a subprogram is not supported error

Tags: vhdl

My code is about a ping pang game using VHDL and maxplus2. I can't get it complied.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
-- use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity center is 
    port ( 
        clk:    in  std_logic;
        ca:     in  std_logic;
        cb:     in  std_logic;
        enable: in  std_logic;
        a:      in  std_logic;
        b:      in  std_logic;
        ball:   out std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
        sa:     out std_ulogic;
        sb:     out std_ulogic;
        over:   inout std_ulogic
    );
end center;

architecture behavior of center is
    signal direction : integer range 0 to 2; 
    signal num : integer range -1 to 17;  
begin
    process (enable,ca,cb,a,b,clk)
    begin        
        if enable = '0' then   
            over <= '0';
            sa <= '0';
            sb <= '0';
        elsif enable = '1' and rising_edge(clk) then
            if direction = 2 then
                if ca = '1' then
                    direction <= 0;       
                    num <= 1;
                elsif cb = '1' then 
                    direction <= 1;
                    num <= 16;
                else
                    direction <= 2;
                    num <= 8;
                end if;
            elsif direction = 0 and num > 0 then
                if b = '1' then
                    if num < 2 then
                        num <= num - 1;
                        direction <= 1;
                    else
                        direction <= 2;
                        sa <= '1' after 10 ns;
                        sb <= '0' after 10 ns;
                        over <= not over after 10 ns;
                    end if;
                end if;        
            elsif direction = 1 and num <= 16 then
                if a = '1' then
                    if num >= 14 then
                        num <= num + 1;
                        direction <= 2;
                    else
                        direction <= 2;
                        sa <= '0' after 10 ns;
                        sb <= '1' after 10 ns;
                        over <= not over after 10 ns;
                    end if;
                end if;
            elsif direction = 0 and num = -1 then
                num <= 8;
                direction <= 2;
                sa <= '0' after 10 ns;
                sb <= '1' after 10 ns;
                over <= not over after 10 ns;
            elsif direction = 0 and num = -1 then
                num <= 8;
                direction <= 2;
                sa <= '0' after 10 ns;
                sb <= '1' after 10 ns;
                over <= not over after 10 ns;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture behavior;
```

But I get a error:

> signal parameter in a subprogram is not supported

I am confused, I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: This code analyzes. Other than superfluous sensitivity list items it should simulate, noting in general the delay mechanism (`after`) in signal assignments are generally ignored and don't result in delays following synthesis. There are no user authored subprograms in this code. It would appear your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: There is no subprogram in this code. Are you sure you sent the correct snippet? On which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think as David also said you need to provide more information. 
What it looks like for me is that your are writing a test bench the above code cannot be synthesized correctly. ISE will tell you that your syntax is ok but the delays are ignored IE the `after` keyword. The `after` keyword is only used in simulation.

That said i would also clean up the code there are a lot of redundancies. FX
The last two `elsif` statements. only one is needed. and the sensitivity list. only `clk` and `enable` should be there.

I've tried to clean up your code:

```
process (enable,clk)
begin        
    if enable = '0' then   
        over <= '0';
        sa   <= '0';
        sb   <= '0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        case( direction ) is

            when 0 =>
                if num > 0 then
                    if b = '1' then
                        if num < 2 then
                            num <= num - 1;
                            direction <= 1;
                        else
                            direction <= 2;
                            sa <= '1' after 10 ns;
                            sb <= '0' after 10 ns;
                            over <= not over after 10 ns;
                        end if;
                    end if; 
                 elsif num = -1 then
                    num <= 8;
                    direction <= 2;
                    sa <= '0' after 10 ns;
                    sb <= '1' after 10 ns;
                    over <= not over after 10 ns;                              
                end if;                
            when 1 =>
                if num <= 16 then
                    if a = '1' then
                        if num >= 14 then
                            num <= num + 1;
                            direction <= 2;
                        else
                            direction <= 2;
                            sa <= '0' after 10 ns;
                            sb <= '1' after 10 ns;
                            over <= not over after 10 ns;
                        end if;
                    end if;                
                end if;                
            when 2 =>
                if ca = '1' then
                    direction <= 0;       
                    num <= 1;
                elsif cb = '1' then 
                    direction <= 1;
                    num <= 16;
                else
                    direction <= 2;
                    num <= 8;
                end if;
            when others => NULL;

        end case ;
    end if;
end process;
```

Try and remove your `after` keywords and see if it will compile then.